# How to call another function in call back function of channel.bind of pusher?

Tags: angular, pusher

I'm using pusher in Angular 8 and i'm trying to call a function and angular's Renderer directive in this code?

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
    channel.bind('my-event', function (data) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

     this.functionname();

     this.renderer.addClass(this.elref.nativeElement,'badge1');


    });
```

but i'm getting errors

```
      Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined
      at Channel.Dispatcher.emit
```

and

```
this.functionname() is not a function..
```

Comment: Try using arrow function instead of normal function.channel.bind('my-event', (data) => { ... }); Also in pusher there is optional third parameter which helps to bind to the particular context.

Comment: yeah for .bind better to use arrow function .